# Apache kafka - windows, How to avoid prefixing every command in CLI

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Recently, the Kafka windows scripts moved to "windows" folder under bin. As of now, the way I am executing the command is to navigate to Kafka installation directory and run the commands, something like

```
PS C:\Users\admin> cd ..
PS C:\Users> cd ..
PS C:> cd .\confluent-5.5.0\
PS C:\confluent-5.5.0> .\bin\windows\kafka-consumer-groups.bat
```

Isn't there anyway to run the commands directly like  ( BTW, I tried adding full path to environment variables, it didnt work )

```
PS C:\Users\admin>kafka-consumer-groups.bat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `C:\confluent-5.5.0\bin\windows` to your `PATH`. It must work. You'll probably need to re-start your shell or session to see that changes.

Comment: it worked, thanks. However, adding environment variable as CONFLUNENT _HOME didnt work, perhaps, it got to do something with it.